# how to handle error 401 in simple ember auth?

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

The problem is the session will expire after a predetermined amount of time. Many times when this happens the ember.js app is still loaded. So all requests to the backend return a **401 {not autorized}** response.

so i need to **redirect user to the login page** and **clear the last token from the session** so that ***isauthenticated*** property becomes false.

I am using custom authenticator.

```
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import ENV from '../config/environment';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Base.extend({

    restore: function(data) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
                resolve(data);
            }
            else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    },
    authenticate: function(options) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: ENV.CONSTANTS.API_URL + '/authentication',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    username: options.username,
                    password: options.password
                })
            }).then(function(response) {
                if(!response.token){
                    Ember.run(function(){
                        reject(response.message);
                    });
                } else {
                    Ember.run(function() {
                        resolve(response);
                    });
                }
            }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    reject(xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText);
                });
            });
        });
    },
    invalidate: function(data) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ENV.CONSTANTS.API_URL + '/authentication/logout'
            }).then(function(response) {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    resolve(response);
                });
            }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    reject(xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I am using ember simple auth 1.0.0. Anybody have a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [`DataAdapterMixin`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/DataAdapterMixin.html) that will automatically handle all 401 response to Ember Data requests and invalidate the session if it gets one. If you're making your own AJAX requests you'd have to handle these responses yourself.

Automatic authorization of all requests as well as automatic response handling was removed in 1.0.0 as it lead to a lot of problems with global state and made the whole library much harder to reason about.

Comment: actions: {
    error: function(error, transition){
      if (error && error.status === 401){
        return this.transitionTo('index');
      }
      return true;
    }
  }, I have handled the 401 in app route using this function. Now how do i invalidate the client ?

Comment: Use the [session service's `invalidate` method](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html#method_invalidate) to invalidate the session.

Comment: But won't it call the custom authenticator's invalidate property? which in my case would try to make an ajax request to logout and it will once again return 401.

Comment: Yes it will call the authenticator's `invalidate` method. I guess the authenticator should handle the fact that invalidation fails because the session is already invalid.